# ARSCNView is nil when embedded in a container view

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, uicontainerview

I have `MainGameViewController` which has a container view that embed `ViewController` that is the initial UIViewController that I got with the template ARKit app. Meaning it has a `ARSCNView` object and an outlet to the storyboard that looks like this in code:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
```

If the `ViewController` is my initial `ViewController`, it works. But if I use it embedded I get an `unexpectedly found nil` crash. I already tried to disconnect and reconnect my `IBOutlet`. This is my `ViewDidLoad` code that has the crash when I set the delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
    addGun()
}
```

And here are some useful screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]